# Access violation at SDL_CreateRenderer

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I use vc++ 2010 express and currently working on a project but when I try to use SDL_CreateRenderer function I get this error:

> First-chance exception at 0x6c8037be in Oyun Projem.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x6c8037be in Oyun Projem.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.
>   The program '[320] Oyun Projem.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

at this line:

```
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

here is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;

window = NULL;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("My first RPG!", 100, 100, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

return 0;
}
```

Here is what I see when debugging:

[image]

Comment: Where does it crash inside SDL when you build SDL in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_CreateWindow` [returns NULL if there is a failure](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow). Your code needs to check for this.

```c
// Your code:
window = SDL_CreateWindow("My first RPG!", 100, 100, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

// Add the following:
// Check that the window was successfully made
if (window == NULL) {
    // In the event that the window could not be made...
    printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I added, there isn't a problem with the window creation. I'm still getting the same error.